# How can I ask for a "revote" on an answer?

Tags: discussion

I found an old question and felt none of the answers hit a particular point of view.  The exact details don't matter much *.  But like most old questions, this one gets few views, and my (perhaps) "better" answer won't get much activity or upvotes.

Is there an accepted way to ask the community to go back and look at an older question and rate answers?

```
   -Bryce
```

Comment: The system automatically shuffles old questions onto the main page, so if you're patient you could see the votes roll in at some unknown future date.  Answering older questions is not typically a rep increasing activity. If you're here for rep, give **great** answers to **new** questions.

Comment: And also, new answers on old questions will "bump" a question back to the main page.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use the "share" link under the answer (or perhaps the question as that give you badges) to promote the answer via the various social media outlets or even your own blog.

   Drive traffic to the answer (or question) to increase the views.
2. Offer a bounty.

   One of the reasons is to **Reward existing answer** so pick that and assign the bounty to the answer in question. This will put the question on the "featured" tab for the time the bounty is open and then shown future visitors that someone thought that the answer was really good.

Answer (score 1):

Chris [pointed out](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/719/2196) the two best to get more attention, so I'm just going to mentioned a few negatives.

First, making minor revisions to questions to get them back on top of the active list is frowned upon. Fixing the tags or some other clean up is appreciated, but no one should add an extra few spaces or other minor revisions for the purpose of "bumping" the question.

And regarding "revoting" there isn't anything today, nor are there any plans that I'm aware of, that would remove all the votes from a question to make everyone cast their votes over again. If a question/answer was modified after the initial vote, a voter can go back and undo their votes, but otherwise those votes are considered relatively permanent.

Comment: Minor edits to bump are clearly bad.  Sometimes a good answer comes late.  Sometimes something changes (example: the discovery that antifreeze in sprinklers, once recommended, can cause explosions and is now heavily discouraged).  "Best question" "best answer" is a bit different than "Current question" "current answer".